# How to create Round Telephone screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-custom-view

I am new to Android and I want to create a Round Telephone dialing screen?
so how to create a screen? Which component need to use `LinearLayout`/`FrameLayout`/`RelativeLayout`, and how to set images for all resolution?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would look into creating your own custom UI component. The documentation can be found here [Android Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

You can use the onDraw() method to draw ellipses and pretty much anything else you need. Then potentially add the numbers to form a dial pad. You can output text via onDraw(). Something that might help is the [Vintage Thermometer Tutorial](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/) this actually draws a round thermometer with numbers on a scale, so it might get you 65% of the way there, while providing a good learning experience. You'll need to strip out the sensor related stuff however that is not too difficult.

As for the dialing, I am not too sure although I would store the numbers pressed somewhere in the activity then have a "dial" button that when pressed does something like

```
try {
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+436641234567"));
   startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("Dialer", "Something went wrong dialing...", e);
}
```

Although with the above the user might have to press dial on your app/widget then again on the actual dial screen where the number will have been populated. Someone here might be able to add some additional information but I haven't seen anything yet to suggest you can dial a number without the user explicitly pressing dial on the phone's dialing app.

You will also need this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

I hope this gets your project underway. If you are struggling I would suggest you start with making a call then sort out the custom UI.